# Standalone Jar Execution From Batch File

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

Below is my Jar structure. This is standalone jar.

```
MyApp.jar
--> .settings
--> com
--> lib
--> META-INF
--> resources
--> .classpath
--> .project
```

I am attempting to execute this jar file from bat file.

I have mentioned classpath and main class in MANIFEST.MF file under META-INF folder from MyApp.jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ./lib/jar1.jar ./lib/jar2.jar ./lib/jar3.jar
Main-Class: com.bank.Main
```

Inside my bat file:
java -jar D:\app\MyApp.jar

Is it correct way to lib folder inside jar?

But still i am facing ClassNotFoundException.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException

Anything i missed out Please advise me.

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException

Comment: Seems like you are missing a dependency jar?

Comment: No.. This is my MANIFEST.MF..

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ./lib/javax.jms.jar
Main-Class: com.bank.Main

Comment: When you start it from cmd, (without bat) does the same error occur?

Comment: try to add this in the class path - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjmsapi20jar.htm

Comment: This is not runnable jar. Just i export as Jar from eclipse and i have modified MANIFEST file. if i execute directly through command prompt D:\app>MyApp.jar. it says "A Java Exception has occurred in alert box".

Comment: i have already added Class-Path: ./lib/javax.jms.jar. My main class inside com folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Put the lib folder outside of your current main jar [MyApp.jar] directory and execute it.**

You have packaged the jar dependency inside your main jar. The intention of Class-Path is to add an external jar to the classpath, with the path relative to the location of the main jar.

Packaging a jar within a jar is not supported by standard Java classloaders. If you want, you can explode the inner jar into the main jar, though. Maven can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Fat jar is not supported in Java by default. There are two options.

1. You can define a custom class loader which has to load jars inside lib directory programmatically.
2. You can manually merge all packages of jars inside lib directory to make a one jar and run it. Refer  [https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-how-to-create-executable-fatjar-without-ide ]

Comment: Thanks for your help.